# GitLab Managed Terraform tf.state backend fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, terraform

I am trying to run Terraform with AWS provider using GitLab CI/CD.
I was using the backend as S3 to store the tf.state file and everything was working fine.

As part of a research, I wanted to experiment with GitLab managed Terraform tf.state.
The documentation can be found in: https://gitlab.mvtest-harbor.live/help/user/infrastructure/iac/terraform_state.md

I followed the same procedure as the document said.
This is how my backend file looks like:

**backend.tf**

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "gitlab-terraform-remote-state" {
  backend = "http"

  config = {
    address = "https://XXXXXX.com/api/v4/projects/32/terraform/state/gitlab-terraform.tfstate"
    username = "arjun"
    password = "password"
  }
}
```

Also I added the below as environment variables in CI/CD in GitLab server.

> PROJECT_ID="" TF_USERNAME=""
> TF_PASSWORD=""
> TF_ADDRESS="https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/terraform/state/old-state-name"

In the .gitlab.ci.yaml, this is how I had described my job:

**.gitlab-ci.yaml**

```
terraform plan:
  stage: terraform-plan
  dependencies:
    - lambda package build
  variables:
    PLAN: plan.tfplan
    JSON_PLAN_FILE: tfplan.json
    STATE: dbrest.tfstate
  cache:
    paths:
      - .terraform
  before_script:
    - alias convert_report="jq -r '([.resource_changes[]?.change.actions?]|flatten)|{\"create\":(map(select(.==\"create\"))|length),\"update\":(map(select(.==\"update\"))|length),\"delete\":(map(select(.==\"delete\"))|length)}'"
    - cd terraform
    - terraform --version
    - terraform init -backend-config=address=${TF_ADDRESS} -backend-config=lock_address=${TF_ADDRESS}/lock -backend-config=unlock_address=${TF_ADDRESS}/lock -backend-config=username=${TF_USERNAME} -backend-config=password=${TF_PASSWORD} -backend-config=lock_method=POST -backend-config=unlock_method=DELETE -backend-config=retry_wait_min=5
  script:
    - cp ../artifacts/$CI_PIPELINE_ID.zip ./
    - terraform plan -out=plan_file
    - terraform show --json plan_file > plan.json
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - plan.json
    expire_in: 2 weeks
    when: on_success
    reports:
      terraform: plan.json
  only:
    - main
  allow_failure: false
  needs: ['lambda package build']
```

Once the pipeline runs, after executing the `terraform init` from the before_script, I am getting this error:

> │ Error: Unable to find remote state
> │
> │   with data.terraform_remote_state.gitlab-terraform-remote-state,
> │   on backend.tf line 1, in data "terraform_remote_state" "gitlab-terraform-remote-state":
> │    1: data "terraform_remote_state" "gitlab-terraform-remote-state" {
> │
> │ No stored state was found for the given workspace in the given backend.

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening?
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Update your terraform backend from local to http. Like this:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 5.0"
    }
  }
  **backend "http" {}**
}
```